# Order API Pre-set parameters

Tags: magento2.3, api

I have a custom module with it's own api requests, but I wish to create an alias to an Magento api request.

My api path:

```
GET    /V1/orders/get-new
```

which is a simple alias to Magento owns **GET /V1/orders** but with predefined parameters:

```
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=is_new
&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0[value]=false
&fields=items[...]
```

I have tried calling OrderRepositoryInterface getList with a search criteria matching the above. This returns all the orders, but the items for each order is only an array of ids and not the full details. It also includes the extension attributes.

Comment: If you get order list which has order status "is_new" then use below native Magento API call using searchCriteria.

http://localhost/magentosample230/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=customer_email&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=test@gmail.com&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=status&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=is_new

Comment: I could do this, but I am trying to simplify the endpoint.